# Pointing all actions without specified view to one concrete view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, viewengine, asp.net-mvc

I am creating advanced site that is based in 99% on one view. I have created the following code which is responsible to point all controllers actions which dont have corresponding view to universal view: ~/Views/Shared/UniversalView.cshtml.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    foreach (IViewEngine engine in ViewEngines.Engines)
    {
        if (engine is RazorViewEngine)
        {
            RazorViewEngine razorEngine = (RazorViewEngine)engine;
            var locationFormats = razorEngine.ViewLocationFormats;
            List<string> l = new List<string>(locationFormats);
            l.Add("~/Views/Shared/UniversalView.cshtml");
            razorEngine.ViewLocationFormats = l.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I am preety sure that there will be much better method to achive that effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a BaseController and all your controller must inherit from it.

Then just add a method in BaseController like

```
    public ViewResult UniversalView(string viewName="UniversalView")
    {
        return View(viewName);
    }
```

From other controllers you can call this method instead of traditional View().
If you will specify the view name it will take that view else default is Universal view.

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return UniversalView();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was considering that solution before, but with one difference, I was thinking about inherit from controller class and overriding the View method and then i get scared cause of controller complexity. IMHO that is good solution but it imposes programmers to remember about deriving from custom controller class as a result it will be hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use that view in all the relevant actions:

```
...
return View("UniversalView");
```

But if you really want to go your way. Have a look at ExecuteResult method [link](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/Types-of-ASPNET-MVC-3-Action-Results.aspx) and use it to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for answer. That solution will be very hard to maintain because  in almost every action I should remember to return View("~/Views/Shared/UniversalView.cshtml");